# Define a random value in JMeter from double values

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm getting a response from JSON in string format like "15703.80" and 398166.00.
Now I need to define randomly value using them.

`${__Random(,,)}` doesn't (number at this function needs to be Integer).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `__Random` to get double format:

```
${__Random(1,999999,)}.${__Random(00,99,)}
```

Comment: acctually I'm receiving two double values to work with them

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to call [RandomUtils.nextDouble()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextDouble-double-double-) function using JMeter's [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextDouble(15703.80\,398166.00).round(2),)}
```

[image]

Comment: apparently works but why those errors, even  expliciting class lang3 class on import

javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextDouble() is applicable for argument types: (null, null) values: [null, null]
Possible solutions: nextDouble(), nextDouble(double, double)